# HP P410i RAID10 performance causing Xen to crash

Tags: raid, hp, hp-smart-array

It seems HP P410 RAID card is causing some of my servers to crash when under high IO.

Configured RAID10 with 4x SAS 15k HDDs.

Is this normal? Do I need some other hardware to add to the RAID card to prevent this?

Comment: Please provide server model, generation, OS version and details...

Comment: Can you explain what caused you to come to this conclusion? Also, is the controller running the latest firmware?

Comment: this does seem to provide insufficient information to provide an answer too. Also, significantly, it isn't clear why your problem "crash" is related to the RAID card.

Answer (score 2):

[HP Smart Array P410 RAID controllers](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/arraycontrollers/smartarrayp410/index.html) are a mature and very stable backend storage solution. Let's assume you're on an HP ProLiant G6 or G7 server.

One item that people tend to forget is that HP introduces new functionality and bugfixes during the course of their server product lifetimes.

If you were to call HP support, you'd hear the same thing I'm saying:

- Make sure your server and all of the related peripherals are up-to-date in firmware. The path of least-resistance, if you can afford some downtime, is to run the [bootable system firmware DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&) on your server. That will get everything to a baseline level.
- Make sure the disks are healthy.
- Install [HP Management Agents](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/agents/index.html) on the system so you can trap Integrated Management Log errors.
- Configure your ILO interface, as that can provide additional information in the case of a system crash.